# How to create a gallery widget with my custom application images for Android

Tags: android, android-widget, widget, android-gallery, android-photos

I would like to create a widget for my application. I want it to be like the default gallery widget or Youtube widget where users can scroll through the stack of card. I have some custom images in my application. I want to display these custom images and let the user scroll through it. When he click on the image I want to take him to the application.

Is there any kind of library or any code sample which I can use to do this. Please let me know any information that would be helpful for me. Thank you for your time and efforts.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionality which you want can be achieved by using the `StackView` feature.
    Here I am providing you some links check out , it will help you definately.
    Links:
    1) [StackView1](http://mytutorialonline.com/android/stackview)
    2) [StackView 2](http://www.thaicreate.com/mobile/android-stackview.html)
    3) [StackWidget](http://docs.huihoo.com/android/3.0/resources/samples/StackWidget/src/com/example/android/stackwidget/index.html)

Comment: Thank you very much. You get my 100 reputation points. I am sure this is what i was looking for. Will give it a try soon.

Answer (score 0):

Ya you can do this using Gallery widget..

This is galleyview in XMl:

```
<Gallery 
    android:id="@+id/Gallery01" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
```

This will enable you to scroll horizontally,and from that u can do functionality for that..U can google for Galleyview option ,there are lots of tutorials available..

Comment: I have edited my question to add a image. Can you tell me if I can achieve the above with this? Thank you once again for your time and efforts.

Comment: Gallery view will support only horizontal scrolling..But in your case i think u have to look for some other..